# Google SEO indexing of the url

Tags: url, seo, indexing

Say if i have

> www.xxx.com/origin-to-destination/date/time

, will google index

> www.xxx.com/origin-to-destination **or** www.xxx.com/origin-to-destination/date/time

or both

Comment: You want to post this question here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google will index *the page* not its url.

However, those elements can be omitted when displaying links as a response to a search criteria. Whatever seems to be repeated for many links in the same domain will be replaced by "...".

As far as dates and times go, google will definitely make use of them while choosing the best match for a search criteria.